# Access Browser Cookies from Android App?

Tags: android, browser, cookies

Is it possible to lookup native browser cookies in a custom Android App? I am not talking about WebView cookies. In my app I want to check if a user visited a website using the normal browser. Are browser cookies stored in a pubic directory somewhere on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to do this.